# How to get the first td value from tr with Javascript?

Tags: javascript, tr

```
<tr>
  <td>Test Data</td>
  <td>2016</td>
  <td>59</td>
  <td>10-12-2014</td>
  <td><a href="#" class="delete-item secondary-content"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></a></td>
 </tr>
```

I have a table where I have data in a row as it is defined above. What I want to do is, when the `<i>` is clicked then I want to get the first value of line which is "Test Data".

The rows are in a div which has id `#list`.

```
del(target,title) {
  if (target.className === 'fa fa-trash') {
    // Here I need the first td(which is the title) that I can compare in LocalStorage and delete that specific item
  }
}

document.getElementById('list').addEventListener('click', function (e) {
  const tr = e.target.parentElement.parentElement.parentElement;
  console.log(tr);

  del(e.target, title);
});
```

This gives the following console output:

> ```
> <tr>
>   <td>Test Data</td>
>   <td>2016</td>
>   <td>59</td>
>   <td>10-12-2014</td>
>   <td><a href="#" class="delete-item secondary-content"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></a></td>
> </tr>
> ```

From this point, how can I reach the first `<td>` without using jQuery?

Comment: `var td_first = tr.children[0]` is the first td

Answer (score 1):

I would start by having your listener for the click a bit more specific so its not triggering on any click on the entire table.

Then you were very close by getting the `tr`, from there you can pass the tr into the `del` function and use [getElementsByTagName](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getElementsByTagName) on the `tr` to return the first `td` from the `tr`.

Then you can use [removeChild](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/removeChild) to delete the first td you just queried from the `tr` parent node.

Here is an example:

```js
function del(e){
    let firstTD = e.getElementsByTagName("td")[0];
    console.log(firstTD);
    e.removeChild(firstTD);
}

document.querySelectorAll('#list .fa').forEach(function(trash) {
  trash.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    const tr = e.target.parentElement.parentElement.parentElement;
    del(tr);
  });

});
```

```html
<div id="list">
  <table>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>Test Data</td>
        <td>2016</td>
        <td>59</td>
        <td>10-12-2014</td>
        <td><a href="#" class="delete-item secondary-content"><i class="fa fa-trash">trash</i></a></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Test Data 2</td>
        <td>2015</td>
        <td>33</td>
        <td>11-23-2012</td>
        <td><a href="#" class="delete-item secondary-content"><i class="fa fa-trash">trash</i></a></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```